# ASP.NET Web API: DateTime binding not working in json body

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datetime, asp.net-web-api

For `DateTime` type, if I have a `DateTime` property inside a class then I try to model bind that class with HTTP post json body, the `DateTime` property does not get bound, how so? But if I use parameter binding, it's working fine. So below code works

```
[Route("v1/taxiqi")]
[HttpPost]
public object UpdateTaxiQI(string status, DateTime updateTime)
{
    ...
}
```

But not for below code

```
[Route("v1/taxiqi")]
[HttpPost]
public object UpdateTaxiQI(TaxiQI taxiQI)
{
    ...
}
public class TaxiQI
{
    public string Status;
    public DateTime UpdateTime;
}
```

I am using the latest ASP.NET Web API. Fields are working as it is working on my other API, besides, Status field is successfully bound. And I already tried properties, same result.

Sorry, I found out the root cause, it is caused by our code base is using a custom `DateTimeConverter` for `JSON.NET` and it expects a JavaScript style ticks instead of a date string

Comment: Where is your getter and settter?

Comment: Please update your post to show your sample JSON.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET WebAPI are you using?  Earlier versions use `DataContractJsonSerializer`, see [Json serializers in ASP.NET and other](https://techblog.dorogin.com/json-serializers-in-asp-net-and-other-e12d3d62933f).

Answer (score 2):

Your `TaxiQI` class is incorrect.
The JSON works with public properties not public fields. Change your class to this:

```
public class TaxiQI
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdateTime  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am using the latest ASP.NET Web API. Fields are working as it is working on my other model, besides, Status field is successfully bound

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Svek's answer, it may be wiser to use a `Nullable<DateTime>` or `DateTime?` instead. Null values are an intrinsic possibility whenever you deserialize data.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the root cause, my bad, it is caused by our code base is using a custom DateTimeConverter for JSON.NET and it expects a JavaScript style ticks instead of a date string